# Mecanum car with 4 motors

Tags: ada

I am trying to rotate a [mecanum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecanum_wheel) car 360 degrees to right. The car uses 4 motors along with L298N driver. Every other direction works fine, only when I try to rotate the car 360 degrees it rotates opposite side. LEFT is left side wheels; RIGHT is right side wheels. Here is the code:

```ada
with MicroBit.IOs;
with MicroBit;
with movement;
procedure Main is
   Speed : constant MicroBit.IOs.Analog_Value := 1023; --between 0 and 1023
   Forward : constant Boolean := True; -- forward is true, backward is false
begin
   --  We set the frequency by setting the period (remember f=1/t).
      MicroBit.IOs.Set_Analog_Period_Us(20000); -- 50 Hz = 1/50 = 0.02s = 20 ms = 20000us 
   --LEFT
   --front   
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(6, Forward); --IN1
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(7, not Forward); --IN2
   
   --back
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(2, Forward); --IN3
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(3, not Forward); --IN4
   
   --RIGHT
   --front
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(12, not Forward); --IN1
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(13, Forward); --IN2

   --back
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(14, not Forward); --IN3
   MicroBit.IOs.Set(15, Forward); --IN4
   
   MicroBit.IOs.Write (0, Speed); --left speed control ENA ENB
   MicroBit.IOs.Write (1, Speed); --right speed control ENA ENB
   loop
      null;
   end loop;    
 
end Main;
```

I tried to do it with procedure at first, but it did not work. I tried to do it on main to find the issue did not work. The weird part is that when I make the car go front it works just fine; when I try to make one side of the car go opposite direction for some weird reason the control suddenly happens opposite way.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to help without the actual hardware to test on, but googling datasheets and tutorials for L298N suggests the max value for speed may be 255, not 1023. Could this be related to your issue?

Anyway, I would declare some types and helper procedures, and move the magic numbers out of the control logic. Something like this:
(disclaimer: It haven't compiled or tested any of this...)

```ada
   type Wheel_Pins is
   record
      Pin1 : Microbit.IOs.Pin_ID; -- IN1 / IN3
      Pin2 : Microbit.IOs.Pin_ID; -- IN2 / IN4
   end record;
   
   
   type Sides is (Left, Right);
   type Ends is (Front, Back);
   
   
   type Spin_Direction is (Off, Backward, Forward);
   
   subtype Wheel_Speed is MicroBit.IOs.Analog_Value range 0..255; 

   
   procedure Spin_Wheel( Wheel : Wheel_Pins; Direction : Spin_Direction) is
      function Low return Boolean renames False;
      function High return Boolean renames True;
   begin
      case Direction is
         when Off =>
            Microbit.IOs.Set(Wheel.Pin1, Low);
            Microbit.IOs.Set(Wheel.Pin2, Low);
         when Backward =>
            Microbit.IOs.Set(Wheel.Pin1, Low);
            Microbit.IOs.Set(Wheel.Pin2, High);
         when Forward =>
            Microbit.IOs.Set(Wheel.Pin1, High);
            Microbit.IOs.Set(Wheel.Pin2, Low);
      end case;
   end Spin_Wheel;
   
   
   procedure Set_Speed(Speed : Wheel_Speed; Vehicle_Side : Sides) is
     To_Analog_Value : constant array(Sides'Range)  --'
        of Microbit.IOs.Pin_ID := (Left => 0, Right => 1);
   begin
      MicroBit.IOs.Write (To_Analog_Value(Vehicle_Side), Speed);
   end Set_Speed;
   
   procedure Stop_All_Wheels is
   begin
      for Wheel of Wheels'Range loop
         Spin_Wheel(Wheel, Off);
      end loop;
   end Stop_All_Wheels;
```

The pin numbers could then be "hidden" like this:

```ada
   Wheels : constant array(Ends, Sides) of Wheel_Pins := 
      (Front => (Left => Wheel_Pins'                                   --'
                   (Pin1 => 6, 
                    Pin2 => 7), 
                 Right => Wheel_Pins'                                  --'
                   (Pin1 => 12, 
                    Pin2 => 13)), 
       Back => (Left => Wheel_Pins'                                    --'
                   (Pin1 => 2, 
                    Pin2 => 3), 
                Right => Wheel_Pins'                                   --'
                   (Pin1 => 14, 
                    Pin2 => 15)));
```

I would then test each wheel individually, before combinations of wheels, to make sure the code works as expected:

```ada
   Stop_All_Wheels;
   
   Set_Speed(Left, 60);
   Set_Speed(Right, 60);

   -- test all wheels, both forward, backward and off,
   -- in the following order: front-left, front-right, rear-left, rear-right
   for Vehicle_Side in Wheel'Range(2) loop
      for Vehicle_End in Wheels'Range(1) loop
         for Direction in reverse Spin_Direction'Range loop
            Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Vehicle_End, Vehicle_Side), Direction);
        delay 2.0;
     end loop;
      end loop;
   end loop;

   
   -- test two wheels at a time:
   for Direction in reverse Spin_Direction'Range loop
      for Vehicle_End in Wheels'Range loop
         Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Vehicle_End, Left), Direction);
      end loop;
      delay 2.0;
   end loop;
 
   -- test rotation clockwise
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Front, Left), Forward);
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Back, Left), Forward);
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Front, Right), Backward);
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Back, Right), Backward);
   delay 2.0;
   Stop_All_Wheels; 
    
   -- test rotation counter-clockwise
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Front, Left), Backward);
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Back, Left), Backward);
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Front, Right), Forward);
   Spin_Wheel(Wheels(Back, Right), Forward);
   delay 2.0;
   Stop_All_Wheels; 


   -- test speed settings   
   for Wheel of Wheels'Range loop
      Spin_Wheel(Wheel, Forward);
   end loop;

   Speed_Up: for Speed in Wheel_Speed'Range loop
      Set_Speed(Left, Speed);
      Set_Speed(Right, Speed);
      delay 0.01;
   end loop Speed_Up;
   
   delay 1.0;
      
   Speed_Down: for Speed in reverse Wheel_Speed'Range loop
      Set_Speed(Left, Speed);
      Set_Speed(Right, Speed);
   end loop Speed_Down;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The speed is correctly setup I think. The number 1023 is not the actual speed but a PWM value. So in this case 1023 is the maximum Pwm value and that gives the maximum voltage. So pwm value 1023 is speed 255. But I found my error. The error was not in my code but the cables. I had connected it opposite way. Anyways thanks for replying with code I really liked the way you implemented it and I am gonna try to implement that way aswell.